# Advice (Best practices) for handling large number of large 2D arrays in HDF5 files

Tags: hdf5

I am using a python program to write a 4000x4000 array into an hdf5 file.
Then, I read the data by a c-program where I need it as an input to do some simulations. I need approximately 1000 of these 4000x4000 arrays (meaning, I am doing 1000 simulation runs).

My question now is the following: Which way is "better", 1000 separate hdf5 files or one big hdf5-file with 1000 different dataset (named 'dataset_%04d')?

Any advice or best practices behaviour for this kind of problem is greatly appreciated (as I am not too familiar with hdf5).

---

In case, this is of interest, here is the python code I am using to write the hdf5 file:

```
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File( 'data_0001.h5', 'w' )
h5f.create_dataset( 'dataset_1', data=myData )
h5f.close
```

Comment: Why don't You just test and tell us ;) I'm not sure there is a correct answer. HDF5 does not have file size limits, so if Your use case requires accessing datasets fast, then putting them to one file may be an advantage, this way the time spent on opening files can be avoided (and on HPD file systems at least this time can be significant).

Comment: sort of what I am doing at the moment. I decided to give the one-big-file-approach a try, which should result in a file size of ~ 40 GB. My question was aiming at getting to know how experienced hdf5-user would handle this. From what I read online meanwhile, I got the impression that this would be the one-file approach. Thanks for confirming my assumption about the file size limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really interesting as I'm currently dealing with similar problem.

## Performace

To investigate the problem a little closer, I have created following file

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

def one_file(shape=(4000, 4000), n=1000):
    h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')

    for i in xrange(n):
        dataset = np.random.random(shape)
        dataset_name = 'dataset_{:08d}'.format(i)
        h5f.create_dataset(dataset_name, data=dataset)
        print i

    h5f.close()


def more_files(shape=(4000, 4000), n=1000):

    for i in xrange(n):
        file_name = 'data_{:08d}'.format(i)
        h5f = h5py.File(file_name, 'w')
        dataset = np.random.random(shape)
        h5f.create_dataset('dataset', data=dataset)
        h5f.close()
        print i
```

Then, in IPython,

```
>>> from testing import one_file, more_files
>>> %timeit one_file(n=25) # with n=25, the resulting file is 3.0GB
1 loops, best of 3: 42.5 s per loop
>>> %timeit more_files(n=25)
1 loops, best of 3: 41.7 s per loop

>>> %timeit one_file(n=250)
1 loops, best of 3: 7min 29s per loop
>>> %timeit more_files(n=250)
1 loops, best of 3: 8min 10s per loop
```

The difference is quite surprising to me, for `n=25` having more files is faster, however this is no longer truth for more datasets.

## Experience

As others noted in comments, there is probably no correct answer as this is very problem specific. I deal with hdf5 files for my research in plasma physics. I don't know if it helps you but I can share my hdf5 experience.

I'm running lots of simulations and output for a given simulation used to go to one hdf5 file. When a simulation finished, it dumped it's state to this hdf5 file, so later I was able to take this state and extend simulation from that point (I could change some parameters as well and I don't need to start from scratch). The output from this simulation went again to the same file. This was great - I had only one file for one simulation. However, there are certain drawbacks with this approach:

1. When a simulation crashes, you end up with a file that is not 'complete' - you can't start new simulation from that file.
2. There is no simple way, how you can safely take a look into hdf5 file when another process is writing to that file. If it happen that you try to read from and another process is writing to, you end up corrupted file and all you data is lost!
3. I don't know of any simple way how you can delete groups from a file (I anyone know a way, let me know). So, if I need to restructure a file, I need to create new one from it (`h5copy`, `h5repack`, ...).

So I end up with this approach which works much better:

1. I'm periodically flushing state from a simulation and after that I'm writing to a new file. If simulation crashes, I need only delete last file and I don't lost that much of cpu time.
2. I'm currently only plotting data from all files but the last one. Note that there is another way: see [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/swmr.html), but my approach is definitely simpler and I'm ok with that.
3. It is much better to process more small files than one huge file - you see the progress and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ziky. Actually, you are not the only plasma physicist here working with hdf5 files ;)

I decided to do the following: for the input of the simulations (basically the mesh) I use one big hdf5 file (the same file for all simulations). At the moment they are running sequentially (one simulation, then another and so on), so no parallel access to that file - although I plan to change that, let's see if it is still working then. Since I also want to have access to the results during the simulations, I decided to have one output file per run (for the same reasons like yours).

Comment: Sounds good to me, @Alf. I'm also using parallel access to h5 file as my simulation is written in Fortran + MPI. I use Python only for processing of results. And I think you need to use mpi for parallel access to the file (but I might be wrong). I spent quite a lot of time dealing with parallel I/O routines. It's quite tricky to be able to write to file only from one process or from all at once. If you're interested, let me know and I can share some more experience.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, I know, but I thought I'd share my experiences. My data sizes are smaller, but from a simplicity-of-analysis standpoint I actually prefer one large (1000, 4000, 4000) dataset. In your case, it looks like you'd need to use the `maxshape` property to make it extendable as you create new results. Saving multiple separate datasets makes it hard to look at trends across datasets since you have to slice them all separately. With one dataset you could do eg. `data[:, 5, 20]` to look across the 3rd axis. Also, to address the corruption problem, I highly recommend using `h5py.File` as a context manager:

```
with h5py.File('myfilename') as f:
    f.create_dataset('mydata', data=data, maxshape=(1000, 4000, 4000))
```

This automatically closes the file even if there is an exception. I used to curse incessantly due to corrupted data and then I started doing this and haven't had a problem since.